# Which browsers don't support a HTTP DELETE with jQuery.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

The jQuery documentation for jQuery.ajax() says the following:

> Note: Other HTTP request methods, such
>   as PUT and DELETE, can also be used
>   here, but they are not supported by
>   all browsers.

jQuery itself says it supports IE 6.0+, FF 2+, Safari 3.0+, Opera 9.0+ and Chrome.
So which (if any) of the above does not support an HTTP DELETE?

Comment: I was having this problem. It happened with JQuery 1.10 in IE 10 and Firefox,  but not Chrome. My local dev server that was hosting the page with the AJAX did not have a good SSL cert, and I was ignoring it. It was hitting another server on my box hosting the REST service (no SSL at all). Once I removed the S from the HTTPS in the URL of the page with the form, it worked for both browsers. GET was working fine in all cases.

Answer (score 25):

The short answer is:

**All recent browsers (and even old ones) support HTTP DELETE.**

It's not clear why there is this note in the jQuery documentation, unless they are referring to very old browsers like Netscape 1 or IE 2.

For information, I've tried an ajax DELETE request in IE6 and even with this browser it works. If it works with IE6, it's safe to assume it works with any other browser.

Comment: IE8,9 can't send ajax with DELETE/PUT

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456820/problem-with-jquery-ajax-with-delete-method-in-ie

Comment: Can anyone confirm/refute @user2503775 claim about IE8/9?

Comment: @Yarin, it work on IE8/9 too. I've just tried an ajax DELETE request in IE6 and even with this browser it works.

Comment: @Yarin I'm having issues with IE9 DELETE using jQuery. --- looks like the issue is that I'm having trouble adding auth headers.

Answer (score -10):

Chrome. I'm using both PUT and DELETE in my project, in Firefox and Safari everything works fine, but Chrome executes error callback.

Comment: I just tested sending PUT and DELETE requests to stackoverflow.com using Chrome and XMLHttpRequest and it works fine. I get back status 200 and the response body as I expected. It works with both a synchronous and asynchronous request.

Comment: which version of chrome did you test this with @Ivana?