# How to send a PUT/DELETE request in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, httprequest, put

`GET`:`$.get(..)`

`POST`:`$.post()..`

What about `PUT/DELETE`?

Comment: Better that we need loading as well

Answer (score 1018, accepted):

You could use the [ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) method:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/script.cgi',
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a note, if you're using an IIS webserver and the jquery `PUT` or `DELETE` requests are returning 404 errors, you will need to enable these verbs in IIS. I've found this to be a good resource: http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/05/28/resolve-404-in-iis-express-for-put-and-delete-verbs.aspx

Comment: BE AWARE: `"The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers."` from: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options

Comment: @andi As per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757187/which-browsers-dont-support-a-http-delete-with-jquery-ajax any browser from IE6 on supports these http methods. Unless you're developing for an *ancient* browser, you can safely use http methods beyond "GET" and "POST".

Comment: Also, [you can't pass in form data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088955/how-to-pass-data-in-the-ajax-delete-request-other-than-headers).  It has to go through the URI.

Comment: for versions after 1.9 you can use `method` or `type`

Comment: just inlining @xavier's note regarding passing data via URI, you would have to specify the data as query-string like so `url: urlCall + '?' + $.param({"Id": Id, "bolDeleteReq" : bolDeleteReq})` (see the link in his comment for the full example).

Answer (score 137):

[`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) will work.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'script.php',
   type: 'PUT',
   success: function(response) {
     //...
   }
});
```

Comment: PUT is need `contentType: "application/json"`

Comment: Is there any difference between this answer and Darin Dimitrov's? I assume they were both created at the same time, and therefore there wasn't any plagiarism, but I don't see what this answer adds (apart from 940 reputation to Jacob).

Answer (score 79):

We can extend jQuery to make shortcuts for PUT and DELETE:

```
jQuery.each( [ "put", "delete" ], function( i, method ) {
  jQuery[ method ] = function( url, data, callback, type ) {
    if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
      type = type || callback;
      callback = data;
      data = undefined;
    }

    return jQuery.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: method,
      dataType: type,
      data: data,
      success: callback
    });
  };
});
```

and now you can use:

```
$.put('http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22786755/edit', {text:'new text'}, function(result){
   console.log(result);
})
```

copy from [here](http://stepansuvorov.com/blog/2014/04/jquery-put-and-delete/)

Comment: Delete doesn't expect *data* while put does, not to say that $.get and $.post can have different signatures while here you are hardcoding it to one

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia - 
1. Delete doesn't expect data while put does
---->  The third line handles this scenario
2. $.get and $.post can have different signatures 
----> This is only creating additional jquery methods for delete and put. get and post have their own jquery methods.

Answer (score 31):

Seems to be possible with [**JQuery's ajax function**](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) by specifying

`type: "put"` or 
`type: "delete"`

and is not not supported by all browsers, but most of them.

Check out this question for more info on compatibility:

[**Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

Answer (score 11):

From [here](http://homework.nwsnet.de/releases/9132/), you can do this:

```
/* Extend jQuery with functions for PUT and DELETE requests. */

function _ajax_request(url, data, callback, type, method) {
    if (jQuery.isFunction(data)) {
        callback = data;
        data = {};
    }
    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: callback,
        dataType: type
        });
}

jQuery.extend({
    put: function(url, data, callback, type) {
        return _ajax_request(url, data, callback, type, 'PUT');
    },
    delete_: function(url, data, callback, type) {
        return _ajax_request(url, data, callback, type, 'DELETE');
    }
});
```

It's basically just a copy of `$.post()` with the method parameter adapted.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an updated [ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) call for when you are using JSON with jQuery > 1.9:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/v1/object/3.json',
    method: 'DELETE',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(result) {
        // handle success
    },
    error: function(request,msg,error) {
        // handle failure
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use [`jQuery.ajax`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) :

> Load a remote page using an HTTP
>   request.

And you can specify which method should be used, with the [`type` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) :

> The type of request to make ("`POST`" or
>   "`GET`"), default is "`GET`". 
> Note: Other
>   HTTP request methods, such as `PUT` and
>   `DELETE`, can also be used here, but
>   they are not supported by all
>   browsers.

Comment: do you know which browsers do not support `PUT` or `DELETE`?

Comment: Broken ones, if they're not capable of HTTP :^)

Answer (score 4):

[ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

look for param **type**

Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

For brevity:

```
$.delete = function(url, data, callback, type){

  if ( $.isFunction(data) ){
    type = type || callback,
    callback = data,
    data = {}
  }

  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: callback,
    data: data,
    contentType: type
  });
}
```

Comment: No data field I guess

Answer (score 3):

If you need to make a `$.post` work to a Laravel `Route::delete` or `Route::put` just add an argument `"_method"="delete"` or `"_method"="put"`.

```
$.post("your/uri/here", {"arg1":"value1",...,"_method":"delete"}, function(data){}); ...
```

Must works for others Frameworks

> Note: Tested with Laravel 5.6 and jQuery 3

Answer (score 1):

I've written a jQuery plugin that incorporates the solutions discussed here with cross-browser support:

https://github.com/adjohnson916/jquery-methodOverride

Check it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with AJAX !

For `PUT` method :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'path.php',
  type: 'PUT',
  success: function(data) {
    //play with data
  }
});
```

For `DELETE` method :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'path.php',
  type: 'DELETE',
  success: function(data) {
    //play with data
  }
});
```

Comment: This was already said years before you posted this answer. This is just noise, adding totally nothing new.

Answer (score 1):

## CRUD

this may make more sense

#### CREATE (POST)Request

```js
function creat() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: URL,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(DATA1),
    success: function () {
      var msg = "create successful";
      console.log(msg);
      htmlOutput(msg);
    },
  });
}
```

#### READ (GET)Request

```js
// GET EACH ELEMENT (UNORDERED)
function read_all() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: URL,
    success: function (res) {
      console.log("success!");
      console.log(res);
      htmlOutput(res);
    },
  });
}

// GET EACH ELEMENT BY JSON
function read_one() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: URL,
    success: function (res) {
      $.each(res, function (index, element) {
        console.log("success");
        htmlOutput(element.name);
      });
    },
  });
}
```

#### UPDATE (PUT)Request

```js
function updat() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    url: updateURL,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(DATA2),
    success: function () {
      var msg = "update successful";
      console.log(msg);
      htmlOutput(msg);
    },
  });
}
```

#### DELETE (DELETE)Request

```js
function delet() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: deleteURL,
    success: function () {
      var msg = "delete successful";
      console.log(msg);
      htmlOutput(msg);
    },
  });
}
```

#### [GitHub Reference](https://github.com/ProjectTutorials/AJAX-CRUD)

Answer (score -1):

You could include in your data hash a key called: _method with value 'delete'.

For example:

```
data = { id: 1, _method: 'delete' };
url = '/products'
request = $.post(url, data);
request.done(function(res){
  alert('Yupi Yei. Your product has been deleted')
});
```

This will also apply for

Comment: This just does a post.

Comment: This will work with rails, the _method is used to tunnel http methods over POST (although you should probably only use this with forms - they're only able to do get/post).

Comment: This will also work with Laravel if you're doing it from a form with the POST method.