# Sending a DELETE request from Sinatra

Tags: ruby, rest, sinatra, httprequest, http-delete

I am trying to develop a RESTful Sinatra application. Now, I know how to respond to a delete request with something like

```
delete '/user/:id' do |id|
   #do something in the model
end
```

What I am interested in is how do I get to execute that method. I can't have link that does a DELETE instead of a GET, can I?

The only solution I found so far is sending a DELETE request via jQuery: [How to send a PUT/DELETE request in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153917/how-to-send-a-put-delete-request-in-jquery)

I tried looking into different RESTful Sinatra projects on github but my Ruby knowledge is probably to limited to get how they are doing it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Put following line in your code.

```
use Rack::MethodOverride
```

It will help you interpret post methods with parameter "`_method`" with value "`delete`" as put.
 Then you can write

```
delete '/user/:id' do |id|
```

Comment: in fact, I this is necessary if he is using a Modular app. Sinatra Classy apps get this set by default.

Comment: For Sinatra modular style, instead of "use Rack::MethodOverride" you can add this to your app class that inherits from Sinatra::Base: "set :method_override, true"

Answer (score 16):

I thinks it's like the Rails way. You need define a params '_method' with 'delete' value and add it on your form.

When you POST you form with this particular params, you do a DELETE request in sinatra.

Like :

```
<form action="/search" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0">
    <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete" />
  </div>
</form>
```

It's the same with PUT method

Comment: any reference as to why?

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use Curl:

```
curl -X DELETE http://host/user/1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  %form{:action => "/note/delete/#{@note.id}", :method => "post"}
    %input{:type => 'submit', :name=> "_method", :value => 'delete', :class => 'button'}
```

You can also trigger the delete route with a button like so

Answer (score 0):

see also [Call Sinatra delete route with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270817/call-sinatra-delete-route-with-jquery/13597435#13597435) for how to do this with jQuery and JSON at the front end and Sinatra on the back end.