# Call Sinatra delete route with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby, sinatra

I am pretty new to Sinatra and am making a simple todo app that utilizes basic CRUD functionality.

In the backend I have working routes and have tested everything. I wanted to incorporate some front end functionality and decided to use jQuery to help with that. I have a current piece of code in jQuery that adds a css class to one of the todo items when that item is clicked. I wanted to include a button that says "Delete completed tasks" that would collect the tasks with the class of "completed" and than trigger the Sinatra route which would delete the tasks from the database. The current Sinatra route is:

```
delete "/hub/note/:id" do
   n = Note.get params[:id]
   n.destroy
   redirect '/hub'
end
```

How do I get jQuery and Sinatra to communicate the delete the items with the class of "completed". Any help would be incredibly useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizing the [method_override](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__enabledisable_the_post__hack) trick/hack, you can get what you want by doing this:

```
jQuery.post("/hub/note/" + id, {_method: "delete"}, callback);
```

Anything leveraging [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/MethodOverride.html), including Sinatra and Ruby on Rails, should have this behavior.

Comment: Thanks! Could I just grab the elements with class "completed" and send the above method on it?

Comment: Sure, that would work.  The way I'd probably do this, personally, is by adding a data-id="1" or similar property to each tr (or li? whatever) that embodies the entire note and then do this:
    $(".completed").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).closest("tr").data("id");
        $.post("/hub/note/" + id, {_method: "delete"}, function(){
            // whatever
        });
    });

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery code.

```
$.post('/user/' + user.id, {_method: 'delete'}, function(result_data) {
  console.log('DELETE result', result_data);
}).error(function(){
  console.log("Error trying to DELETE");
});
```

In your Sinatra code

```
delete "/user/:id" do
  if request.xhr?
    content_type :json
    id = params[:id].to_i
    user = User.find_by_id(id)
    if !user
      status 404
      return {:success => false, :message => "Invalid ID supplied."}.to_json
    end
    user.destroy
    return {:success => true, :id => id, :message => "The User with ID #{id} was deleted."}.to_json
  end
  status 403
  return "<html><head><title>Error 403</title></head><body><h2>Expected an AJAX call.</h2></body></html>"
end
```

If your sinatra app is not a `modular` app then also include a `set :method_override, true` line with your other `set`s.