# How to pass data in the ajax DELETE request other than headers

Tags: jquery, ajax

Below is my Ajax request for a `DELETE` request:

```
deleteRequest: function (url, Id, bolDeleteReq, callback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: urlCall,
        type: 'DELETE',
        headers: {"Id": Id, "bolDeleteReq" : bolDeleteReq},
        success: callback || $.noop,
        error: errorCallback || $.noop
    });
}
```

Is there any alternative way to pass the data other than in the `headers`?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Read this Bug Issue: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11586

Quoting the [*RFC 2616 Fielding*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.7)

> The `DELETE` method requests that the origin server delete the resource **identified by the Request-URI**.

So you need to pass the data in the URI

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlCall + '?' + $.param({"Id": Id, "bolDeleteReq" : bolDeleteReq}),
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: callback || $.noop,
    error: errorCallback || $.noop
});
```

Comment: So you can send data with DELETE before jquery 1.7.2 ?

Comment: @user568109 I just checked various versions of jQuery and it seems that no version supports it.. (*i tried down to 1.3.2*)

Comment: @user568109 but to be honest, i am not sure if the jquery cuts them off or the browser ..

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully pass through the data attribute in the **ajax method**. Here is my code

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/api/Gigs/Cancel",
     type: "DELETE",
     data: {
             "GigId": link.attr('data-gig-id')
           }

  })
```

The ***link.attr*** method simply returned the value of  *'data-gig-id'* .

Answer (score 0):

Playing with `data` in AJAX request with DELETE type will take up a lot of your time trying to deal with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')`.

A good oldschool approach (pass the data in the URI as well as you do for GET request) will save your time:

```
let requestUrl = urlCall + '?Id=' + Id + '&bolDeleteReq=' + bolDeleteReq;

$.ajax({
url: requestUrl,
type: 'DELETE'
```