# Using .each to delete all items by id using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it even possible to bulk delete items from a server with ajax? I am at a complete loss here.

I am trying to run an each function to pull the url id for each item on my server and then plug it into a ajax delete type call. This makes sense to me, but I am still new at programming and I feel like I could be miles off.

Any amount of insight on this would be a huge help. Thanks.

```js
$('#delete-friends').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends',
    success: function(friends) {
      var scratchFriend = $.each(friends, function(i, friend) {
        var friendID = (friend.id);
        console.log(friendID);

        $ajax({
          type: 'DELETE',
          url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends/'
          friendID ','
          success: function() {
            console.log('Friend Deleted Successfully!');
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#delete-friends {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 70%;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="friendForm">
  <button id="delete-friends">Delete all of the friends?</button>
  <h4>Be a friend</h4>
  <p>Name:
    <input type='text' id='name'>
  </p>
  <p>Age:
    <input type='text' id='age'>
  </p>
  <button id="add-friend">Join us Friend</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Try `url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends/' + friendID,` in your `DELETE` `Ajax` request.

Comment: You can also pass multiple parameters in a single DELETE request too . Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088955/how-to-pass-data-in-the-ajax-delete-request-other-than-headers

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to send an array of friend ids to the backend - you'll just need to tweak the backend a bit:

```
$('#delete-friends').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends',
    success: function(friends) {
      if (!friends) {
          return;
      }

      var friendIds = [];

      $.each(friends, function(i, friend) {
        friendIds.push(friend.id);   
      });

      $ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends/'
          data: {
            friendIds: friendIds
          },
          success: function() {
            console.log('Friend Deleted Successfully!');
          }
      });

    }
  });
});
```

Or even better - create a delete method which will take a user and delete all his friends:

```
    $('#delete-friends').on('click', function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/delete/friends',
        data: {
            user: 'johnbob'
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (!data) {
              return;
          }

          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    });
```

But I'm guessing you are using the http://rest.learncode.academy/ API so you can't really change the backend.

From what I can see in the docs at learncode you can append the id of the friend in the url to delete it. This should do the trick:

```
        // -- SAME CODE FROM ANSWER --
        $ajax({
          type: 'DELETE',
          url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/johnbob/friends/' + friendID
          success: function() {
            console.log('Friend Deleted Successfully!');
          }
        });
        // -- SAME CODE FROM ANSWER --
```

Comment: Yeah manipulating the backend isn't really an option. I would have to do it through an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the server has a bulk delete function where you pass all ids you want to delete. Deleteing them one by one is a bit much traffic because for every id/request you send to the server you send also meta information about the request, which would be redundant. You could reduce this request to one by sending all ids.