# Body of Http.DELETE request in Angular2

Tags: angular, rest, http-delete

I'm trying to talk to a somewhat RESTful API from an Angular 2 frontend.

To remove some item from a collection, I need to send some other data in addition to the removée unique id(that can be appended to the url), namely an authentication token, some collection info and some ancilliary data.

The most straightforward way I've found to do so is putting the authentication token in the request Headers, and other data in the body.

However, the Http module of Angular 2 doesn't quite approve of a DELETE request with a body, and trying to make this request

```js
let headers= new Headers();
headers.append('access-token', token);

let body= JSON.stringify({
    target: targetId,
    subset: "fruits",
    reason: "rotten"
});

let options= new RequestOptions({headers:headers});
this.http.delete('http://testAPI:3000/stuff', body,options).subscribe((ok)=>{console.log(ok)}); <------line 67
```

gives this error

```
app/services/test.service.ts(67,4): error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

Now, am I doing something wrong syntax-wise? I'm pretty sure a DELETE body is supported per RFC

Are there better ways to send that data?

Or should I just dump it in headers and call it a day?

Any insight on this conundrum would be appreciated

Comment: use POST and rename wording of delete to findAndDelete to make sense.

Comment: @YOU Yes I can, but shouldn't I try to keep destructive actions distinct from non-destructive ones right at the request type level?

Comment: then you will have to put it in querystring, but normally you put id of what you want yo delete in url, and authentication bearer in ajax header to send delete request.

Comment: After a couple of hours searching a solution and receiving a lot of errors, I finally used POST method and now all works.

Answer (score -12, accepted):

Definition in http.js from the **@angular/http**:

> delete(url, options)

The request doesn't accept a body so it seem your only option is to but your data in the URI.

I found another topic with references to correspond RFC, among other things:
[How to pass data in the ajax DELETE request other than headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088955/how-to-pass-data-in-the-ajax-delete-request-other-than-headers)

Comment: Is there a open issue on github for this topic? I think a optional body parameter be should definitely added.

Comment: The two other answers prove this answer wrong and it shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: The provided link for this answer points to jquery ajax delete, not Angular 2 as specified on the question. This shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer shouldn't be downvoted, the RFC says that DELETE method does not support request body. So even though there may be workarounds to put it there, it's technically a hack.

Comment: for people in 2021, unfortunately, this is the right answer. delete shouldn't support request body at all. +1

Answer (score 223):

The `http.delete(url, options)` does accept a body. You just need to put it within the options object.

```
http.delete('/api/something', new RequestOptions({
   headers: headers,
   body: anyObject
}))
```

<s>Reference options interface:
https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions</s>

**UPDATE**:

The above snippet only works for Angular 2.x, 4.x and 5.x.

For versions 6.x onwards, Angular offers 15 different overloads. Check all overloads here: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#delete

Usage sample:

```
const options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }),
  body: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'test',
  },
};

this.httpClient
  .delete('http://localhost:8080/something', options)
  .subscribe((s) => {
    console.log(s);
  });
```

Comment: RequestOptions is deprecated.

Comment: Cannot find name 'RequestOptions'. i get this error in angular 10

Comment: @SachiniWitharana, if you read it again, the `RequestOptions` has been deprecated a while back. Since v6, the httpClient provide different overloads instead of an interface.

Comment: You just saved me))

Answer (score 29):

If you use Angular 6 we can put body in `http.request` method.

[Reference from github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19438#issuecomment-346596988)

You can try this, for me it works.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
    http.request('delete', url, {body: body}).subscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

In Angular 5, I had to use the `request` method instead of `delete` to send a body. The documentation for the `delete` method does not include `body`, but it is included in the request method.

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

this.http.request('DELETE', url, {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }),
  body: { foo: bar }
});
```

Comment: If I try this method the Request Method contains OPTIONS instead of DELETE. Are you sure this is still working?

Comment: @Jochen I am pretty sure this works for me and sends DELETE request in Angular 5

Comment: The problem has been found, it was the server that didn't answer with the correct OPTIONS and thus a DELETE was never send by the client because of that.

Answer (score 19):

You are actually able to fool `Angular2 HTTP` into sending a `body` with a `DELETE` by using the `request` method. This is how:

```
let body = {
    target: targetId,
    subset: "fruits",
    reason: "rotten"
};

let options = new RequestOptionsArgs({ 
    body: body,
    method: RequestMethod.Delete
  });

this.http.request('http://testAPI:3000/stuff', options)
    .subscribe((ok)=>{console.log(ok)});
```

Note, you will have to set the request method in the `RequestOptionsArgs` and not in `http.request`'s alternative first parameter `Request`. That for some reason yields the same result as using `http.delete`

I hope this helps and that I am not to late. I think the angular guys are wrong here to not allow a body to be passed with delete, even though it is discouraged.

Comment: I realize to late that @n4nd0_o's does the same thing but still using the original delete method. I'll leave this answer anyhow for an alternative solution.

Comment: Yes @Hampus, we essentially provide the same answer. Yours is a bit more "verbose", nevertheless, the same solution :D

Answer (score 12):

Below is a relevant code example for Angular 4/5 with the new HttpClient.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

public removeItem(item) {
    let options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }),
      body: item,
    };

    return this._http
      .delete('/api/menu-items', options)
      .map((response: Response) => response)
      .toPromise()
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

For angular 10, you can use also the generic request format and the DELETE method:

```
http.request('DELETE',  path, {
            body:body,
            headers: httpHeaders,
            params: ((params != null) ? params : new HttpParams())
        })
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked perfectly for me. Why does this not have more upvotes?

Comment: @AlexWillenbrink Probably because this question is over 5 years old and this answer is merely months old

Comment: this worked for me too! Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Below is an example for Angular 6

```
deleteAccount(email) {
            const header: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
                .append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')
                .append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken'));
            const httpOptions = {
                headers: header,
                body: { Email: email }
            };
            return this.http.delete<any>(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + '/api/Account/DeleteAccount', httpOptions);
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

In Angular 13 this works well for me:

```
const options = {
   headers: this._headers,
   body: JSON.stringify(user)
};

return this._http.delete<DeleteVirtualAssistantResult>(`${this._apiUrl}/users`, options);
```

Answer (score 1):

The REST doesn't prevent body inclusion with DELETE request but it is better to use query string as it is most standarized (unless you need the data to be encrypted)

I got it to work with angular 2 by doing following:

```
let options:any = {}
option.header = new Headers({
    'header_name':'value'
});

options.search = new URLSearchParams();
options.search.set("query_string_key", "query_string_value");

this.http.delete("/your/url", options).subscribe(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the relevant code example for Angular 2/4/5 projects:

```
let headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});

let options = new RequestOptions({
  headers: headers,
  body: {
    id: 123
  }
});

return this.http.delete("http//delete.example.com/delete", options)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return err;
  });
```

> Notice that `body` is passed through `RequestOptions`

Answer (score 0):

In Angular Http 7, the DELETE method accepts as a second parameter `options` object in which you provide the request parameters as `params` object along with the `headers` object. This is different than Angular6.

See example:

```
this.httpClient.delete('https://api-url', {
    headers: {},
    params: {
        'param1': paramValue1,
        'param2': paramValue2
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deleteInsurance(insuranceId: any) {
    const insuranceData = {
      id : insuranceId
    }
    var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        });
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: reqHeader,
            body: insuranceData,
        };
    return this.http.delete<any>(this.url + "users/insurance", httpOptions);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the deprecation of **RequestOptions**, sending data as body in a DELETE request is not supported.

If you look at the definition of **DELETE**, it looks like this:

```
    delete<T>(url: string, options?: {
      headers?: HttpHeaders | {
         [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
      observe?: 'body';
      params?: HttpParams | {
          [param: string]: string | string[];
         };
      reportProgress?: boolean;
      responseType?: 'json';
      withCredentials?: boolean;
     }): Observable<T>;
```

You can send payload along with the DELETE request as part of the **params** in the **options** object as follows:

```
this.http.delete('http://testAPI:3000/stuff', { params: {
    data: yourData
     }).subscribe((data)=>. 
        {console.log(data)});
```

However, note that params only accept data as **string** or **string[]** so you will not be able to send your own interface data unless you stringify it.

Comment: The httpClient no longer offers the interface RequestOptions, but it provides several overloads and the overloads allow body as part of the request options. 
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#delete i.e.Overload #15