# DELETE with Angular 2 (typescript)

Tags: angular, api, typescript

I want to include a DELETE request in my angular application. GET and POST works perfect.

Please find the important part of my user.service.ts file below:

```
deleteMethod(a: A): Promise<any> {
  return this.http.delete(this.apiURL, a)
    .toPromise()
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

If I call the request, I get the following error:

> TypeError: options.search.clone is not a function.

Do you have any ideas how to solve it?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: can you post the 'a' variable values? ie http options

Comment: Is `a` suppose to be `RequestOptionsArgs`?

Comment: You should pass `RequestOptionsArgs` as a parameter into your `delete` method. What is the type of `a`, actually what is `A`?

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. `A` referes to a typescript file which defines the structure as the following example:

`export class Device {

  hello: string;

  constructor(userObj) {
    this.hello= userObj.hello;
  }
}`

For that, I guess, I already defined the `RequestOptionsArgs`, right? What could I do else?

THANKS A LOT ;-)

Comment: What is your purpose of passing `a` as a parameter into `delete` method?

Comment: With `a`, I send some information through the `delete` method that the backend knows which entity it should remove.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Body of Http.DELETE request in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819336/body-of-http-delete-request-in-angular2)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this amazing solution ;-)

Comment: See this answer for adding the body to the options object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40857437/6059889