# How to add a body to Angular HttpClient delete function

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Our project is migrating to *Angular4*, and use `@angular/common/http Httpclient` as the default network tool. But I found there are no `body` params in delete function. How do I add the body to delete function? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Body of Http.DELETE request in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819336/body-of-http-delete-request-in-angular2)

Comment: he is asking about the new HttpClient not the old http module

Comment: but the implementation which he is seeking remains same for both the cases, try going through the link shared.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions

Comment: I can not find a RequestOptions-Like lib in common/http. And the options in HttpClient.delete just support for:headers, observe, params(not body), reportProgress, responseType, withCredentials

Comment: @HongyangDu see the overloaded methods http://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#delete

Comment: @SumitAgarwal Thanks Agarwal~ But the overloaded method just has the changes on responseType and observe type. There still no place for body.

Comment: for future readers - since Angular 4.3 (this includes Angular 5+) they removed the body from the delete method of angular HttpClient the alternative is to use `http.request()` like Andrii Ivanyk posted below. it was removed because the specification for Delete is unclear regarding the use of BODY in it.

Answer (score 120):

You may use a universal `request` method on the HttpClient class instead. This method has the body in options.
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#members


e.g
`this.http.request('delete', 'url', { body: ... })`

Comment: @StefanFalk probably because the "proper" way to delete stuff in a RESTful way is to have a unique URL for each unique resource (e.g.: `/clients/<id>`). But real life APIs are seldom RESTful, unfortunately.

Comment: @JosephTinoco No I just mean the call itself. There could easily be a `this.http.delete()` method that wraps this s.t. the interface gets more intuitive.

Comment: @StefanFalk That's kinda my point. The "intuitive" interfaces are all RESTful, everything else is possible but only with the ugly/less intuitive `this.http.request()` method. It's like Angular is saying "if you want nice, readable code, you gotta go RESTful in the backend".

Comment: In Angular 9+ you will need to `this.http.request('DELETE', 'url', { body: ... })`. In my case the uppercase method string was necessary.

Answer (score 31):

```
const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }), body: your body data
};


return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.httpClient.delete(URL, httpOptions)       
                   .subscribe(res => {     
                       resolve(res);
                   }, err => {               
                       resolve(err);
                   });
    });
```

by using httpOptions, you can set header and body in it.
please refer this https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#delete-a-hero

Comment: Not sure what version of Angular you're using, but this doesn't work in Angular 5 using the HttpClient.  The typings file indicates body doesn't exist.  You need to use `this.http.request` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46316857/1148107

Answer (score 2):

I also get this problem and my solution is creating a new `HttpRequest` of delete method, then clone this request, reset its body with your data.

```js
let req = new HttpRequest('DELETE', 'url');
let newReq = req.clone({body: [10]});
this.http.request(newReq).subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The `clone()` is required, because the body still can not be directly set in the  `new HttpRequest()`.

Comment: Indeed, creating an HttpRequest with method "delete" and passing directly the body in the constructor does not work.
However, it works fine with method "post"