# How to request api delete action in Angular

Tags: angular, rest, api, http, http-method

So in my angular project, I've API call in my workspace.service.ts file and I was able to create others request like getWorkspace and createWorkspace, etc.. but not delete request.

I'm new to API Call or requesting backend stuff but I think that I need to do some call for delete actions.

So what I'm trying to do in my project is to create a delete button that allow user to delete current workspace.

```
export class Workspace {
    guid: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    type: WorkspaceType;
    userRole: WorkspaceRole;
    charts?: any[];
}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { first, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Workspace } from 'src/app/shared/models/workspace.model'; //Code above

export class WorkspaceService {

  loadedWorkspaces: Workspace[]

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getWorkspace(guid: string) {
    return this.http.get<Workspace>(`${environment.api.chart}/workspaces/${guid}`).pipe(first());
  }

  getUserWorkspaces() {
    return this.http.get<Workspace[]>(`${environment.api.chart}/workspaces`).pipe(tap(workspaces => this.loadedWorkspaces = workspaces),first());
  }

  createWorkspace(workspace: Workspace) {
    return this.http.post<Workspace>(`${environment.api.chart}/workspaces`, workspace).pipe(first());
  }
  deleteWorkspace(workspace: Workspace){
    //Delete request

  }
```

I'm not really sure what to do for deleteWorkspace and I tried copying the code from above and just change the HTTP method to this.http.delete but get an errors on the "workspace" and it said, "No overload match this call".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply pass workspace id to delete the workspace.

```
 deleteWorkspace(workspace: Workspace) {
    return this.http.delete<Workspace>(`${environment.api.chart}/${workspace.guid}`);
  }
```

OR

If you want to pass the body in delete request, this question might help you: [How to add a body to Angular HttpClient delete function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049082/how-to-add-a-body-to-angular-httpclient-delete-function)