# Delete a data row from table in Angular (Spring- Rest API, MongoDB)

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm developing a crud application on members in a library and I want to perform the delete operation but it does not work. Please help me to solve this issue.

**Rest API**

```
@DeleteMapping("/members")
public Member delete(@RequestBody Member member){
    repository.delete(member);
    return member;
}
```

As for the REST Api it's working finely, I checked it using Postman.

**Http service.ts**

```
export class Member{
constructor(
public id:string,
public name:string,
public fBook:Book,
public contact:string,
){
}
}

export class Book{
constructor(
public author:string,
public name:string,
public year:string
){
}
}

export class HttpClientService {

constructor(
private httpClient: HttpClient
) { }

private url= 'http://localhost:8080/members';

deltMem(member: Member){
return this.httpClient.delete<Member>(this.url);
}
}
```

**deltecomp.ts**

```
export class DeleteComponent implements OnInit {

members: Member[];

constructor(
 private httpClientService: HttpClientService
 )  { }


deleteMember(members:Member){
this.httpClientService.deltMem(members).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res);
  }
)
}}
```

Comment: 1. What doesn't work - could you clarify that a bit more? 2. Do you get any error?

Comment: Also, you aren't using the `member` payload when you make the api call from angular.

Comment: What does res show after cal?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a common and good practice to send a `body` content for a REST `Delete` method.
Even it's not forbidden. I don't recommend you to use it.  [You can read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request) for more details.

The fact that `Angular` don't support it as common and simple way. You can but you need extra code, see [this post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049082/how-to-add-a-body-to-angular-httpclient-delete-function).

If you are designing your backend architecture (you are free to adapt and design it I mean), in this case I strongly recommend you to use an `id` to identify the resource you would like to delete :

`DELETE http://your-api-service/members/15`

It's more clear, simple, human readable.

So your `Spring Boot` code should be :

```java
@DeleteMapping("/members/{memberId}")
public Member delete(@PathVariable("memberId") Integer memberId){
    Member memberToDelete = repository.findById(memberId);
    // ... delete member
    return memberToDelete;
}
```

and your `Angular code` :

```js
deleteMember(member: Member){
  return this.httpClient.delete<Member>(`${this.url}/${member.id}`);
}
```