# passing a body containing a json array of items for delete in angular

Tags: angular, rest, http-delete

I have a REST API as below which is using the HTTP `DELETE` method. I have to pass this body in that HTTP `DELETE` method in Angular. Please help. I cannot change the structure of this body

```
{
  "transactions": [
    {
      "eventId": "21012200237172",
      "productCode": "LC",
      "id": "LC20110000090023"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You may pass a body when using the universal `http.request` variant. Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46049082/how-to-add-a-body-to-angular-httpclient-delete-function

Comment: @timcy you can accept the answer if that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass body in httpdelete with options

```
let apiUrl = 'yourUrl';
let transactions = [{
    "eventId": "21012200237172",
    "productCode": "LC",
    "id": "LC20110000090023"
}];

const options = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }),
  body: {
    transactions: transactions
  },
};

this.httpClient
  .delete(apiUrl, options)
  .subscribe((s) => {
    console.log(s);
  },err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: but , with this i can just use the body to be passed in options . How about if i have to observe the response status code. with the above code observe:'response' is not supported in options

Comment: the subscribe method will grab your response. You can find the response and response status code both in the variable "s" in above code snippet

Comment: it does contain the response but it doesnt contain the response status

Comment: can you please give the response screenshot from chrome-developer tool's network tab?

Comment: and another fact if the delete is not successful then the error will have to catch in another callback.if first callback hit then the delete operation is successfull

Comment: see i have updated the answer with catching errors.

Comment: I have handled the error conditions , However for the response status it looks as below: {transactions: Array(1), messageKey: "TRANSACTIONS_DELETE_SUCCESS", message: "The transaction(s) have been successfully deleted.", userLangaugeMessage: "The transaction(s) have been successfully deleted.", userLanguage: "en"}

Comment: please check your comment. you didn't provide any screenshot or anything else

Comment: you can provide pastebin link