# issue with httpClient delete with body in angular 4

Tags: angular, httpclient

issue here with the delete request (in angular 4), as i get a

> requestheaders does not exist in the type requestoptionargs

below is my code:

```
myMethod(id: string, reason: string): Observable<any> {

        const reqHeaders = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          });
        const body =
            `{"reqId": "${id}",
             "reqReason": "${reason}"
            }`;
        return this.httpClient.delete(
            `http://localhost:188/.../1677777555`,
            new RequestOptions({ reqHeaders, body }))
            .map(rez => JSON.parse(rez))
            // .catch(error => this.handleError(error))
            ;
    }
```

on this line is where i get the error `new RequestOptions({ requestHeaders, body }))` Any obvious faults here?

Edit:
another variant

Same body as before and:

```
const options = new RequestOptionsArgs({
    body: body,
    method: RequestMethod.Delete
  });

return this.httpClient.request('http://testAPI:3000/stuff', options);
}
```

now I get a:

> RequestOptionsArgs refers to a type but is beingused as a value here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819336/body-of-http-delete-request-in-angular2/40857437

Comment: Thanks Anuradha, but I think most posts there are for angular 2 not 4 - I get other errors, as above

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

myMethod(id: string, reason: string {
    let params = new HttpParams()
        .append('id', id)
        .append('reason', reason)
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/JSON' });
    return this.httpClient.delete<any>('http://localhost:188/.../1677777555', { headers: headers, params: params })
    .map(rez => JSON.parse(rez));;
```

Comment: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3. According to angular4, the delete should have 2 arguments. The second is options that may contain the body and headers. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#delete I also tried based on this the following (will edit my original post in 5 min). Thanks Joe

Comment: @annepic I made an error check my answer now, I have corrected it

Answer (score 3):

as per documentation try like this : https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#members

can you tryout general request like this

```
let options = new RequestOptionsArgs({ 
    body: body,
    method: RequestMethod.Delete
    headers : reqHeaders
  });

this.http.request('http://testAPI:3000/stuff', options)
    .subscribe((ok)=>{console.log(ok)});
```

Comment: Thank yoiu Pranay, I get this: `Argument of type '{ headers: HttpHeaders; body: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type RequesrOptionArgs | undefined. `

Comment: Your answer pointed me to the right direction. With Angular 6, got it working with `this.http.request('DELETE', url, { body: myObjOrArrayToBody })`