# angular 4 http delete method not accepting request body

Tags: angular4-httpclient

I have a delete request which sends body as part of the request like

```
import {RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    this.http.delete('/api/deleteAddress', new RequestOptions({
       headers: headers,
       body: [{"folder":true}]
    }));
```

Comment: check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819336/body-of-http-delete-request-in-angular2

Comment: there's no body in the RequestOptions, https://angular.io/api/http/RequestOptions, I think because it's deprecated, in my project it isn't, watch it with F12