# How to make a massive delete in angular 4 with an array of ids

Tags: c#, angular, angular-httpclient, angular4-httpclient

I'm trying to make a massive delete, in order to do that I have an `Array<number>` of the ids I want to delete. I can't pass this array as a parameter to the method `this._httpService.delete(uri,options)`. The type of `_httpService` is `Http`.

So I'm looping the array and inside the loop I'm making single calls, but each call is async and I have certain logic to run when the loop ends.

Comment: Why cant you provide the IDs as URL parameters?

Comment: because i don't know how many objects the user is going to delete. I'm showing a list of things and the user select the ones that he want to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can send the id array in the body of a DELETE request, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819336/body-of-http-delete-request-in-angular2#40857437), like so:

```
http.delete('/api/something', new RequestOptions({
    headers: headers,
    body: anyObject    // this would contain your ids
}))
```

So instead of issuing hundreds of requests, have your app make just one with all ids in the body.

Comment: Awsome, and my next question would be: how do i access to that array? I can access to the headers doing in mi backend : Request.Headers.Autrhorization.Scheme for example to get the token.

Comment: Thank you so much, i can access to the array with the next parameter : [FromBody] ids

Comment: I have the next problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50893637/cant-access-to-my-method-delete-of-my-api-rest can you help me?

Comment: RequestOptions was depredacted with the whole @angular/http package since Angular 5. Options now are only an object without specific type.