# Can't access to my method delete of my api rest

Tags: c#, angular, angular2-routing

I'm not able to access to my delete method of my api rest.

If i write the method like this it work:

```
[Route("api/Document/{documentId:int}")]
    [HttpDelete]
    public IHttpActionResult Delete([FromUri]int documentId,[FromBody] int [] documentsId)
    {
        try
        {
            documentCtrl = documentCtrl ?? new DocumentCtrl();
            return Ok(documentCtrl.Delete(documentsId));
        }
        catch (DocumentNotFoundException)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
```

It works, but if i put:

```
[Route("api/Document/MassiveDelete")]
    [HttpDelete]
    public IHttpActionResult MassiveDelete([FromBody] int[] ids)
    {
        try
        {
            documentCtrl = documentCtrl ?? new DocumentCtrl();
            return Ok(documentCtrl.MassiveDelete(ids));
        }
        catch (DocumentNotFoundException)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
```

I don't have acces, any ideas what could it be?

This is my request code:

```
DeleteDocument(id: number): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._httpService.delete(AppModule.service + 'Document/' + id, AppModule.options)
        .map((response: Response) => <boolean>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}//This work if i want to delete one

DeleteDocuments2(ids:Array<number>):Observable<boolean>{
    AppModule.options.body=ids;
    return this._httpService.delete(AppModule.service + 'Document/MassiveDelete', AppModule.options)
        .map((response: Response) => <boolean>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send two parameters in your Api, you need to createa  custom class like follow and send as follows,

```
MyCustomRequest {
   public int[] documentIds;
   public int documentId;
}
```

and then,

```
public IHttpActionResult MassiveDelete([FromBody] MyCustomRequest  request)
```

you can access it as,

```
request.documentIds;
request.documentId;
```

Comment: But i don't want the to parameter i only want the second parameter and then is when it start my problem because i can't access if i put just the second parameter.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: i just only need one parameter, the int[] ids parameter i need. What i was saying if i put the two parameters it works but is not what i want

Comment: can you check what does your chrome developer tools shows on network tab?