# How to send like API to instagram with javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-post, instagram-api

I am trying to register like API call to instagram.

As their dev site told me I call like

```
InstagramAPI.prototype.like = function(){
    var access_token = '211611405.1677ed0.4e0e854196454874b858e21c293b919d';
    var mediaId = '448979387270691659_45818965';
    var apiUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/' + mediaId + '/likes';
    $.post(apiUrl, {access_token : access_token}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }, 'jsonp').done(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }).fail(function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

However, when I inspect with browser tool, it sends GET request and get people who likes that photos.

I have tried this with `$.ajax()` with `?callback=?` parameters and it also does not work.

The main error is

- using `json` type makes Same origin policy problem
- Sending `Post` request automatically change into `Get` request

How can I fix this? Thanks.

P.S.

I already read those articles to fix this, but does not work for me :<

- http://jsfiddle.net/lukekarrys/D3FMg/
- https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/
- [how to post a like or delete an instagram like using instagram api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852810/how-to-post-a-like-or-delete-an-instagram-like-using-instagram-api)