# Call laravel controler from an ajax request with get / put / delete method

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I am having a javascript like this which will call two different controller in two diff situation ....
Now the problem is it is one get method and one is destroy method ... when the call is generated, the controller functions never triggered. No idea wheather the url method is right or not. It is giving the 500 error.

I am also not sure about the response back from the controller. but before that I need to execute the database operation in the controller ... which is not going to execute. advance thanks for the help :)

JS code below :-->

```
function follow_or_unfollow(id,action)
{
    //var dataString = "id=" + id;
    if( action == "follow" ) {
        myUrl = "{{ action('FollowsController@show', 'id') }}" ;
        myMethod = "GET";
    }
    else
    { 
        myUrl = "{{ action('FollowsController@destroy', 'id') }}" ;
        myMethod = "DELETE";

    } 
    var dataString = "id=" + id;
    $.ajax({  
        type: myMethod ,  
        url: myUrl,  
        //data: dataString,
        beforeSend: function() 
        {
            if ( action == "following" )
            {
                $("#following"+id).hide();
                $("#loading"+id).html('<img src="loading.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="Loading...">');
            }
            else if ( action == "follow" )
            {
                $("#follow"+id).hide();
                $("#loading"+id).html('<img src="loading.gif" align="absmiddle" alt="Loading...">');
            }
            else { }
        },  
        success: function(response)
        {
            if ( action == "following" ){
                $("#loading"+id).html('');
                $("#follow"+id).show();

            }
            else if ( action == "follow" ){
                $("#loading"+id).html('');
                $("#following"+id).show();
            }
            else { }
        },
        error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

                    if (xhr.status == 500) {
                        alert("Error 500: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);

                    } else {
                        alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);

                    }
                },
                complete : function(xhr, textStatus) {

                      allert('ok');

                }

    }); 
}
</script>
```

**1st edit**

get a point after the firefox tool check up (as suggested by Chinnu)

It is showing

```
`[18:38:47.658] GET http://localhost/ffdd/public/follows/id [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 230ms]`
```

that means ! the id is not been generated as digit or id variable, it is just going as "id" string. Now need a specific solution , how to send the value of id there .... at the controller througn the JS.

**2nd edit**

If I put the digit or value of id instead of mentioning it by 'id' that means if the value of id can be print directly there it will work . What will be the easier way to do that ?

```
myUrl = "{{ action('FollowsController@destroy', <the value of id>) }}" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `type` of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**NOTE:** You can able to find this errors using in Firefox Tools->Web Developer ->Error Console or CTRL+SHIFT+J

Comment: Thanks for reply bro ! 
This is ok. But if we consider the get or post method here , that is also not been triggered to the controller ! can you find any error in this JS code ?

Comment: Firefox Tools->Web Developer ->Error Console or CTRL+SHIFT+J

Comment: For the testing purpose, you can call like `url: 'your php file',` and call your controller related calling function in that file.

Comment: brothers ! Pls check the edit. Now I am having a specific error !

Comment: can you enable and try this .data: dataString,

Comment: No, brother the datastring is not working. But I have send the data instead by using  myUrl = "{{ action('FollowsController@show', 1) }}" ;

then it is working. That means If I can print the value of ID there it will be working ... is there any easy way to do that ?

Comment: Nop still the 500

message ---- `[19:38:28.906] GET http://localhost/ffdd/public/follows/%22+id+%22?id=1 [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 273ms]`

Comment: http://localhost/ffdd/public/follows/id?id=1  check this url in browser and change the url accordingly

Comment: `[19:57:59.426] GET http://localhost/ffdd/public/follows/id?id=1 [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 189ms]'

still the error

Comment: Can you check your server error log, this is related to the server code.

Comment: No brother this is not a server error cause the controller expecting the value of id directly like `blabla/id=1` and at the same time it is rejecting the empty action call. Can we pass the value to the controller with routes ? any knowledge about that ?

Comment: Where are you getting the id from?  If it's being passed into the view, use `{{ action('FollowsController@show', array($id)) }}`. Remember the curly braces mean PHP, even if inside a `<script>` tag.  You won't be able to get a javascript variable in there, so if you can only access it via JS, you'd have to hardcode the url without using a php helper.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a javascript variable inside a php helper function will not work.  I'm not sure what's passing id into that function, but if it's being passed into the view via PHP, then you should use `{{ action('FollowsController@show', array($id)) }}`

If it's not being passed into the view, then you would have to use `myUrl = '/follow/'+id` and make sure you have routes for both `GET` and `DELETE`.