# How to pass a value from a JS function to a laravel controller?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I am having trouble with JQ and laravel controller.

As this is a JS file which need to call a controller with a value in it.

```
function follow_or_unfollow(id,action)
{
    either route call
        myUrl = "{{ route('follows.show','id') }}" ;

    or controller call

 myUrl = "{{ action('FollowsController@show', 'id') }}" ;

bla bla bla !

}
```

What I need is : to send the value of the id by printing there at the place where 'id' is mentioned. at this moment it is printing as id instead of value of the id. I have tried several things like

`'+id+'`

`'"+id+"'`

and sending data by other ariable. but laravel controller expect to receive data within the route / action method not from outside. Any help will be apreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't run php in a js file. How are you using `follow_or_unfollow()`?

Comment: NO NO bro, the call is goint to fetch the ajax file. I need to know how the url should be setup in this jq which lead the call with the value of id not the 'id' instead !

Comment: you have arguments for `follow_or_unfollow()`...again, how are you using that function? You pass ID in through the function and there should be no laravel template code inside your script file. Javascript can't process php, they run in totally different environments

Comment: brother thanks for your kind reply. Pls check this ---> [Click ME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174667/call-laravel-controler-from-an-ajax-request-with-get-put-delete-method/20174707?noredirect=1#comment30077760_20174707) here I have mensioned the full code. At this question I want only the print value of id instead of printing 'id' which is giving the value as id.

Comment: that code does not show where you call function `follow_or_unfollow()`. Once inside the function you would concatenate the url with `+id`

Comment: `var url= "http://localhost/ffdd/public/follows/"+id`

Comment: but direct call instead of using the controller may cause some security issue. Also the link will be changed from place to place. Cant it be made within that place bro ?

Comment: No it can't.  It's another security issue to be coming up with these ID's with Javascript.  Show us the code you are using to call this function and the code you are using to come up with the ID.  Usually in cases like these, the ID is actually being passed into the form via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Find a solution that works fine at this moment. Thanks Charletfl !

yes the link can do this job as alternative. like this :

```
function follow_or_unfollow(id,action)
{
    either route call
        myUrl = "http://foofoo.com/+id" ;

    or controller call

 myUrl = "http://foofoo.com/+id" ;

bla bla bla !

}
```

in this way the variable value can be passed to the controller but still a researchable question is raised. Like : if we want to implement/print a value inside a php tag what should we do ..

Thanks for helping friends !