# Laravel : How to print Javascript variable in blade view engine?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

```
$('#status').parent().append('<a href="' + data.output.url + '" id="link">Download file</a>');
```

How to print "data.output.url" variable in Laravel View.

Comment: And How to sotre file directly from URL to specific location ?

Comment: You can edit your original post and add your 2nd question to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print JavaScript variable value inside a php tag using blade template in Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177054/print-javascript-variable-value-inside-a-php-tag-using-blade-template-in-laravel)

Comment: This is probably duplicate question. I sorted out very similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28629676/2776843

Answer (score 0):

You can use the curly braces like this in the blade template:

```
$('#status').parent().append('<a href="' + {{ $dataOutputUrl }} + '" id="link">Download file</a>');
```

...Where $dataOutputUrl a php variable passed to the template. The template gets parsed and the variable will get output into the javascript.