# How to handle an HTTP DELETE request

Tags: python, http, pyramid, http-delete

I know how to handle HTTP `GET` and `POST` requests using pyramid, I want to know how I can handle a `DELETE` request. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2153931/2173793), describing how to handle a delete request on the client-side, using ajax.

Do you handle a `DELETE` the same as you would handle a `POST` or `GET` request, on the server side?

I found this in the pyramid [docs](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/viewconfig.html#view-defaults-class-decorator). Though this example uses a `DELETE` request, I am still not sure if it should be treated in the same way as a `POST`.

If a `DELETE` request is handled differently, can you please provide an example of how to handle the request?

I couldn't find anything on SO that gives me the answers that I need...

Comment: The Pyramid link shows you how to handle a `DELETE` request; it's handled just like any other HTTP method. It's no different from a `POST`; only the verb differs.

Comment: Reason why I ask is, it is not working, as I expect... I need it to delete a certain thing from the entity. Currently, it deletes the entity.

Comment: Then ask *that* question instead.

Comment: Just change this question, there are no answers yet.

Comment: I just used POST instead... Thanks for your response though `:)`

Comment: Take a cup of tea/coffee and read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Idempotent_methods_and_web_applications. You may be running into a design flaw if you are not aware of these facts.