# Using ajax with jQuery - url not accepted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to build an ajax request that will eventually allow users to sort a list by clicking buttons next to each item. Here's what I have so far:

```
upLinks.on('click', function(e) {
  var link;
  e.preventDefault();
  link = $(this)[0];
  console.log(link.pathname);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: link.pathname
  });
  return false;
});
```

`console.log(link.pathname)` logs out `/projects/11/project_items/104/sort` to the console, as expected. However, the ajax request returns an error:

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/projects/11 400 (Bad Request)
```

Looking at the server logs, it is in fact going to `/projects/11`, not `/projects/11/project_items/104/sort` for some reason. According to the jQuery docs, `/projects/11` would be the default parameter for ajax in this case, because that's the route of the current page. Which leads me to believe it's ignoring the url parameter altogether.

If I change HTTP method type to `GET`, the ajax runs as expected. Is there some reason `/projects/11/project_items/104/sort` is not an acceptable url for a `PUT` request? I thought that because I'm updating data (with the new position) a `PUT` request would be the most logical option.

Comment: Try doing a network trace (press F12 in Chrome|Firefox and go to Network) to see what's actually being sent.

Comment: Depends if the server can accept PUT requests

Comment: @amphetamachine Thanks for the tip. Through the network tab I was able to see that the PUT request was actually being sent successfully, but then the server was attempting a redirect that triggered the error. So this was a server-side issue.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note, if you're using an IIS webserver and the jquery PUT or DELETE requests are returning 404 errors, you will need to enable these verbs in IIS. I've found this to be a good resource: http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2011/05/28/resolve-404-in-iis-express-for-put-and-delete-verbs.aspx

"The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers." from: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options

Reference stack question: [How to send a PUT/DELETE request in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153917/how-to-send-a-put-delete-request-in-jquery)

Comment: The question is showing that the URLs are going to the wrong place though

Comment: @Quentin but OP said that when the request is changed to "GET", it works as expected, so its not the url, but the "PUT" request, which this answer addresses

Comment: @indubitablee Assuming it's a problem on the server rather than the client.  If it's the client mangling the URL in the PUT request, changing stuff on the server won't help.