# HttpDelete is not working, but when I use HttpPost it does

Tags: c#, http, extjs

I have a method in `ExtJS` that sends to a `C#` method.  On the `ExtJS` the user is using a button to delete a record.  The `C#` method than deletes the record in the database.  When I use `[HttpPost]` in front of the `C#` method it works, when I changed to `[HttpDelete]` I get a "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://localhost:5708/api/record" error.

Here is my `C#` method

```
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("api/record")]

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Deleterecord(int recordInt)
    {

    }
```

Here is my `ExtJS` listener

```
  onClickDeleteButton: function () {
    var viewRecord = this.getViewRecord();
    var viewForm = this.getViewForm();
    if (viewRecord && viewForm) {
      viewForm.updateRecord();
      viewForm.submit({
        url: 'api/record',
        method: "DELETE",
        waitMsg: 'Deleting Record...',
        scope: this,
      });
    }
  },
```

Why is this not working when I use `HTTPPost` but not `HTTPDelete`?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153917/how-to-send-a-put-delete-request-in-jquery) may help you. Also this http://stevemichelotti.com/resolve-404-in-iis-express-for-put-and-delete-verbs/

Comment: Can you open the network tab in your browser and look at the response? Particularly the headers `Allow` value. Does it include the `DELETE` method? If not, you may have to configure it in your web.config.