# ajax to trigger object oriented method for delete

Tags: php, ajax

I have a class file on root of the application, and in that class I have a `public function deleteUser` method. I want to call that method from frontend via ajax. The examples I have seen are something like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/deleteUser.php',
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function(){
                alert('cat deleted');
            }
        });
```

But what is throwing me off is I don't have a php file that just does delete code (deleteCat.php in this above example). I have that delete code inside my class. How am I to trigger an exact method inside a class from ajax without using `url:XX`?

Comment: AJAX doesn't trigger a class or method, it makes a request to a PHP file like any other HTTP request.  You would have *server-side* code which performs the logic you want.

Comment: so if you have a large application, and you want a simple method in it to be triggered, you have to create a file just for that class method? that seems weird to me.

Comment: Who said you have to create a separate file for every method?  That would indeed seem weird to me as well.  But you *would* need to make an HTTP request to some PHP file which would execute your server-side code.

Comment: u will want to send **data** with that ajax request that includes the user id that should get deleted. and maybe check the response to see if successful or exploded rather than just alerting success

Comment: mega6382 i will work through them this week thanks

Comment: did any of the provided solutions work for you?

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

Use data in your Ajax function to post a Json like:

data : { 'type' : 'delete' }

And set type to POST

In you php file do

```
If ($_POST['data']['type'] == 'delete') {
  delete();
}
```

Comment: your answer is incorrect, check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153917/how-to-send-a-put-delete-request-in-jquery

Comment: No. 'DELETE' is a Http Verb 'designed' to delete recourses on the server. So there's nothing wrong in using it...

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following inside the method `deleteUser`:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "DELETE")
{
    //Delete query here
}
```

This will determine if the request is of type `Delete` or not. And if it is you can call your delete query. But make sure that call the method too, just defining it isn't enough.