# How to use DELETE method in ajax for laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.3

In a Laravel project I want to delete an item using ajax.
My route is

```
Route::resource('title','TitleController');
```

Here is my ajax code

```
$.ajax({
        url:'title',
        type: 'post',
        data: {_method: 'delete', _token :token, id : id},
        success:function(msg){

            console.log(msg);

         }
      });
```

So how to use DELETE method in a ajax with a parameter for deleting items ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a PUT/DELETE request in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153917/how-to-send-a-put-delete-request-in-jquery)

Comment: `type: "DELETE"` instead of POST should work without the need for the `_method` field.

Comment: Right apokryfos. I updated my solved code :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct route name,pass the id in the url

```
 url:{{route('title.destroy',['id'=>$title->id]}},
```

or

```
url:{{action('TitleController@destroy',['id'=>$title->id])}}
```

in your controller you do something similar:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
       Title:::find($id)->delete();
       redirect()->to('/')->with('message','Successfully deleted the title');
    }
```

As you have the id in javascript you will need to concatenate it to the url

full code:

```
$.ajax({
        url:'{{url('title')}}'+id,
        type: 'post',
        data: {_method: 'delete', _token :token},
        success:function(msg){

            console.log(msg);

         }
      });
```

Comment: When I use 'resource' in route, laravel automatically call the function according to the method and parameter.... So I don't need to use the specific function name in the URL if I can send the method accurately.... I want to know... Is any process possible in Ajax ? #madalinivascu

Comment: @Arafat what do you mean by that?

Comment: can you post your controller?

Comment: the ajax you are doing right now is passing the id as a request param, the delete route is `title/{id}` not `title`

Comment: ya....but like post or get method we need delete method also for deleting an item ...right ?

Comment: some server are not capable of doing a DELETE request so you do a POST request with a request param `_method` of  `delete` as you are doing right now

Comment: by **delete method** i think you mean controller function, yes you will need a controller function named destroy that takes a id as a param

Comment: no .. I mean DELETE request.....But i am confused that whenever the url is "title/{id}" with DELETE request then I don't need to specify the method name "destroy"...Laravel auto find the method as the request type is DELETE. But in this "  url:{{route('title.destroy',['id'=>$title->id]}}, " I need to provide the method name too

Comment: `title.destroy` is **not** the method name is the route name

Comment: sorry...ya route name. do u understand what i mean now?

Comment: you don't need to use the route name if you don't want, but you will need your url as `title/{id}` and your request param `_method` of `delete` or you will do a update request ,without the `{id}` param and the `_method` param you will do a create request

Comment: send it where??

Comment: #madalinivascu thanks for your help...I have updated the solved code.
Thanks a lot   :)

Comment: don't forget the green check, get read of # your not on instagram or twitter

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solved ajax code

```
$.ajax({
        url:"{{url('title/" +id+ "')}}", //----- OR url :"/title/"+id,
        type: 'DELETE',
        data: {_token :token},
        success:function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            }   
       });
```

Comment: i suggest you use `url:'{{url('title')}}'+id,` from my answer, your url is relative to the current route, if you alter the current route your ajax will be broken searching for a row relative to the new route

Comment: url : `"{{url('title/" +id+ "')}}"`