# AJAX DELETE request in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http-delete

I've always thought that a delete request should be done using type: "DELETE". However, it seems not work in .NET

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/TestController/DeleteTest?id=10',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            // Works
        }
    },
    error: function (erro) {
        console.debug(erro);
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult DeleteTest()
    {
        int id= Int32.Parse(Request["id"]);

        var myTableTest= db.myTable.Where(x => x.id== id).FirstOrDefault();
        db.mytable.Remove(myTableTest);

        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This code works fine! But if I change to type: "DELETE", it won't work anymore. So, does asp.net have HttpDelete?

Thanks

Comment: Works fine? You calling a method named `DeleteTest` but you have shown us one named `DeleteForm`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a PUT/DELETE request in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153917/how-to-send-a-put-delete-request-in-jquery)

Comment: About the method name, it is was only a mistype. It wasn't actually my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is decorated with the `[HttpGet]` attribute. This tells the framework that the method should only be considered if the `GET` verb is used.

If you want it to respond to `DELETE` you need to change the attribute to [`[HttpDelete]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpdeleteattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) instead:

```
[HttpDelete]
public JsonResult DeleteTest()
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just decorate your action with the `[HttpDelete]` attribute instead of `[HttpGet]`. I would also have it set to return an `ActionResult` instead of `JsonResult` and return `new HttpStatusCodeResult(200)` on success in order to make sure your ajax call properly understands the returned result.

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net-mvc we have `HttpGet` and `HttpPost` and in this particular case you should be using `HttpPost` not `HttpGet`, otherwise anybody can hit the url with query string to request deletion of any record, and another thing is to not use magic strings for generating urls instead of that use `Url.Action` method which would take care to generate the correct urls for you.

Change your jquery ajax call to use post:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteTest","Test")',
    data: {id:10},
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
```

and then in your action use `HttpPost` and add parameter to your action method signatures like:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteTest(int id)
{

    var myTableTest= db.myTable.Where(x => x.id== id).FirstOrDefault();
    db.mytable.Remove(myTableTest);

    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` needed in `HttpPost`?