# why do not work delete button in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have task delete button in My laravel application,

this is My blade file delete button

```
<a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/delete" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
```

this is TaskController delete function

```
public function deleteOneProjectTask($projectId, $taskId)
    {
        DB::table('tasks')
            ->where('project_id', $projectId)
            ->where('id', $taskId)
            ->delete();
 return redirect()->route('projects.show')->with('info', 'Task deleted successfully');
    }
```

and this is route

```
Route::delete('projects/{projects}/tasks/{tasks}/delete', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@deleteOneProjectTask',
]);
```

but when I go to delete following error is coming,

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

how can fix this problem?

Comment: it is because link is a get request and not a delete request

Comment: how to make it as delete request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling url by anchor like

```
<a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/delete" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>
```

is actually by `get` http verb not `DELETE` as you make route for `delete` so you need to make it for `get` instead `delete` like

```
Route::get('projects/{projects}/tasks/{tasks}/delete', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@deleteOneProjectTask',
]);
```

Or you have to call as `delete` http verb, either by `method='DELETE'` in form tag or by `ajax` where you can make it http verb as `DELETE`

To make a `DELETE` http verb, use `form` with `submit` type button, [Read more..](https://www.w3.org/TR/form-http-extensions/#http-delete-form)

```
<form action="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/delete" method="DELETE">
    <button type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
</form>
```

Also take a look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2153931/2815635) to call http verb `DELETE` by ajax. To call ajax use `onclick` Event to pass related id's in url

Comment: how to make it method delete

Comment: @DNK : I given one way with `form` tag check updates

Comment: actually I am using mouse over icons to delete tasks. so, I need **<a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/delete" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>** this type link to My tasks.

Comment: @DNK : Is this works except css style ? I mean calling `delete` type ?

Comment: If you are not able to change css for button, you can use `<a href="javascript: document.getElementById('form_id').submit()" title="Delete" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>` and put `id='form_id'` in `form` tag
`

Comment: what did you mean I cant understand.

Comment: **<a href="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/delete" class="editInline"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a>** is working with **get** methods but I need use delete methods with above buttons.

Comment: I am saying about `<form action="/projects/{{ $project->id }}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}/delete" method="DELETE">
    <button type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
</form>` what I given in ans , Is this works for you ?

Comment: OMG : no boss I am asking about `DELETE` keep route as `delete` type and use above given code, and share if works ?

Comment: if use route as delete following error is coming **MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:**

Comment: @DNK : And also using `above` form tag code with button right ?

Comment: ok, you can try with ajax , or try to search about `delete` supported versions. if not succeed stay with `GET`