# How to call method name in form action while working with REST API using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello everyone I am working on REST API in Codeigniter but i am surprise  in normal codeigniter when we give method name after controller for example(localhost/project_name/controller/user_get) it will get all users from table but while working with REST API in Codeigniter I am getting unknown method error please tell me how to define method name while rest api in form action

below i have written  my code

in view page when i want to click button in form it should call method and retrieve all users

```
<form method="post" action="<?=base_url('index.php/Api/user_get')?>">

    <button>Click Here</button>


</form>
```

controller code

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require(APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Api extends REST_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }


  public function user_get() {   //this method will get all users from table
            $r = $this->user_model->read();
            $this->response($r);
        }


      public function user_put() { //this method will insert users details 
           $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
            $data = array('name' => $this->input->get('user_name'),
                'pass' => $this->input->get('user_password'),
                'type' => $this->input->get('user_type')
            );
            $r = $this->user_model->update($id, $data);
            $this->response($r);
        }

}
```

Below code written in model

public function read() {

```
   $query = $this->db->query("select * from `tbl_user`");

   return $query->result_array();
```

}

Getting error like this

[image]

Comment: i'm not sure if you understood the principle here; if you send a form via post you simply have to use `<form method="post" action="<?=base_url('index.php/Api/user')?>">` according to html standards you can't use `put` in a form so you've to rename your method `user_put()` to `user_post()`, if you don't want that you should use a library like jQuery (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153917/how-to-send-a-put-delete-request-in-jquery?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), angular or something similiar...

Comment: @sintakonte user_get or user_put is just name you cangive any name to the method  here  what i want to ask is in form action whatever url address is given it should go to that method only but  I am getting error unknown method again I am not using rout mostly people use in codeigniter

Comment: no you don't understand the principle here ... i'll write an answer for clarification

Comment: @sintakonte method is working fine without rest api but ineed rest api for my project so in this case observe      below method  how controller extends actually in all github following this way to work with rest api we have to load from libraries .                      require(APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Api extends REST_Controller {}

Comment: @sintakonte please show me how to do this  i need it,  it's very urgent  .

Comment: dude if you want an answer with quality you've to gv me some time - i posted it now - it should clarify your problem and you should be able to understand what the `REST_Controller` is doing...

Comment: @sintakonte ok take your time please give me solution for this problem

Comment: Hi MSp! What is your controller name here?

Comment: @AnandPandey my controller name is Api but using extends from rest_controller

Comment: @MSp: Can you extend only to CI_controller and try again? In your custom controller you extend ci_controller or not?Give your REST_controller here?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function users_get()
{
    $users = $this->user_model->get_all();

    if($users)
    {
        $this->response($users, 200);
    }

    else
    {
        $this->response(NULL, 404);
    }
}
```

Comment: the conditions which you mention it will check whether data is present in table or not if yes it will show else it will show  no data but  in my case form action is not calling to perticular method

Comment: how to call method in form action ?it is showing error because form not getting  method name which i have mentioned in form action even it is present in controller with same name without any mistake.

Comment: as this return response in JSON , you have to submit your form using Jquery - AJAX and get json response in ajax

Comment: you can use POSTMAN to check your api response

Comment: when i click on submit button it is not calling to that method , this is my question  i know output will get in json form

Comment: this is GET method , your form action is POST method

Comment: POSTMAN working fine but in <form method="post" action="?"> not working

Comment: try with GET method in form . `<form method="GET" >`

Comment: have you got response ?

Comment: please tell me how to  make this post method even in form action using post method please show the way to write in controller

Comment: when click on submit button form will go to method name which is written in controller but here error is pointing that unknow method why

Answer (score 0):

The Rest Controller is designed for the purpose of reacting with the different kind of `HTTP` Methods which means you have only one `URL` but a lot of varying methods.

the allowed `methods` by default are `get, delete, post, put, options, patch, head`. For more clarification take a look [here](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php#L172):

### Real World Example based on your question:

First of all, everytime you type in an address in your browser and press `Enter` you make a `GET` Request.

You don't need the `_get` suffix in your browser - the rest Controller will take care of. It recognises this and adds in a self acting way the `_get` suffix to your function which means, you've to type in your browser:

`localhost:81/sample_api/index.php/api/user/`

The Rest Controller now checks your Type of `Request`, recognises it as a `GET` request and tries to call the function `user_get`.

The same applies to your form, if you build a form with the method `POST` and an action like `<?=base_url('index.php/Api/user')?>` the Controller knows its a `POST` Request and tries to call the function `user_post`.

So your controller should look like:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require(APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Api extends REST_Controller 
{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }


    public function user_get() {   
        //this method will get all users from table
        $r = $this->user_model->read();
        $this->response($r);
    }


    public function user_post() { //this method will insert users details 
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('user_name'),
            'pass' => $this->input->post('user_password'),
            'type' => $this->input->post('user_type')
        );
        $r = $this->user_model->update($id, $data);
        $this->response($r);
    }

}
```

and your view

```
<form method="post" action="<?=base_url('index.php/api/user')?>">
    <button>Click Here</button>
</form>
```

**Update**

The Rest_Controller allows you to define the different kind of Request Methods through an `field` called `_method`, which means you can use manually set it in your form like the following:

```
<form method="post" action="<?=base_url('index.php/api/user')?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
    <button>Click Here</button>
</form>
```

You just have to set the variable `enable_emulate_request` in your rest config to `true`.

You can find this information [here](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php#L1049)

---

All this *magic* stuff is happening in the `_remap` method as you can see [here](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php#L665).

Comment: instead of error it should show user details from table i have added my model code also  I didn't did any wrong .

Comment: so  if  i want to update users details i will pass id but in form how can i write put method normally we do like this                                               <form method="POST" action="<?=base_url('index.php/Api/user_get/'.$id)?>"></form>

Comment: sry dude, but are you even reading what i'm posting ? do you even understand a little bit of them what i wrote here ? you are talking about a rest api but want  a simple MVC - why do you even want to use a rest service at the first place ?

Comment: yes i have read you the post which have mentioned ,but in postman they have option GET,POST,PUT,DELETE so all operation will work fine in POSTMAN but now coming to form  if i want to update or retrieve value of user what should be the action i have to write because my requirement is api that should work everywhere even in app also.

Comment: i gv you this exact answer in my first comment of your question - use jquery, angular or something like that - the basic form method doesn't support that... for more information you can take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: basic form method will not support REST API?

Comment: previously you told use jquey  or ajax ok i did so many times so i here i want to do simple form action without jquery or ajax

Comment: basic form method will only partial support the REST API - because the html standard defines the possibility of sending a form only in 2 ways `POST` and `GET`- thats it - you got all the references in my previous comments - btw i'll edit my post, there is another option

Comment: thanks for your support  and valuable time  but l have one more doubt can i use same code for android app ? because concept of api is only a single link can work so many places like in php ,apps

Comment: of course you can - thats the purpose of an api ;) - btw i've updated my answer - because i found a way how you can manage your forms ...

Comment: when i use only user it calling to last method because all methods name are like this    user_put(),user_get(),user_delete,user_post()  suppose i want to get results so if after controller if you mention only user  it will call the method user_post  not user_get()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171745/discussion-between-sintakonte-and-msp).

Answer (score 0):

You are not add echo and second thing not load helper url it will help you.

1. If you want to post than you will correct it
2. If you want to get than you ha

```html
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Api/user_put'); ?>">
<form method="get" action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/Api/user_get'); ?>">
```

ve to call like

Comment: do you have idea how to create REST api in codeigniter  inform me

Comment: yes i made lots but i separate into different controller and folders

Comment: can you please tell me how to define separate method like get,post,put in <form action="?"></form>

Comment: <?=?> is short tag use for php which i had mentioned in my question,if you have amy demo or practice project based on Codeigniter rest api the send the link of that project

Comment: i have created rest api and checked in postman it is working without any issue but i have one form same api i want to  use in form action but whenever i do this getting problem because in postman you call metod name only like this  user_get then call in postman user and perform get or post but in form if i mention same api with full anme it is not working if use only user it is trying to call other methods

Comment: @MSp: you should use method="post" or "get" in the form and they work well.

Comment: already  had used that but nothing worked ,if you have any demo or source code of project kindly send me

Comment: @MSp: Here is the link for basic https://selftaughtcoders.com/creating-processing-form-codeigniter/

Comment: i need api how to define in form with different methods like insert update post not basic way ,because i know that i want to know whatever different api key(post ,put,get ) i have created how to use that in the form .