# Problem with jQuery.ajax with 'delete' method in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I have a page where the user can edit various content using buttons and selects that trigger ajax calls.  In particular, one action causes a url to be called remotely, with some data and a 'put' request, which (as i'm using a restful rails backend) triggers my update action.  I also have a delete button which calls the same url but with a 'delete' request.  The 'update' ajax call works in all browsers but the 'delete' one doesn't work in IE.  I've got a vague memory of encountering something like this before...can anyone shed any light?  here's my ajax calls:

```
//update action - works in all browsers
jQuery.ajax({
  async:true, 
  data:data, 
  dataType:'script', 
  type:'put', 
  url:"/quizzes/"+quizId+"/quiz_questions/"+quizQuestionId,
  success: function(msg){ 
    initializeQuizQuestions();
    setPublishButtonStatus();
  }
});  



//delete action - fails in ie
  function deleteQuizQuestion(quizQuestionId, quizId){
    //send ajax call to back end to change the difficulty of the quiz question
    //back end will then refresh the relevant parts of the page (progress bars, flashes, quiz status)
    jQuery.ajax({
      async:true, 
      dataType:'script', 
      type:'delete', 
      url:"/quizzes/"+quizId+"/quiz_questions/"+quizQuestionId,
      success: function(msg){ 
        alert("success");
        initializeQuizQuestions();
        setSelectStatus(quizQuestionId, true);
        jQuery("tr[id*='quiz_question_"+quizQuestionId+"']").removeClass('selected');        
      },
      error: function(msg){
        alert("error:" + msg);
      }
    });     
  }
```

I put the alerts in success and error in the delete ajax just to see what happens, and the 'error' part of the ajax call is triggered, but WITH NO CALL BEING MADE TO THE BACK END (i know this by watching my back end server logs).  So, it fails before it even makes the call.  I can't work out why - the 'msg' i get back from the error block is blank.

Any ideas anyone?  Is this a known problem?  I've tested it in ie6 and ie8 and it doesn't work in either.

thanks - max

EDIT - the solution - thanks to Nick Craver for pointing me in the right direction.

Rails (and maybe other frameworks?) has a subterfuge for the unsupported put and delete requests:  a post request with the parameter "_method" (note the underscore) set to 'put' or 'delete' will be treated as if the actual request type was that string.  So, in my case, i made this change - note the 'data' option':

```
   jQuery.ajax({
      async:true, 
      data: {"_method":"delete"},
      dataType:'script', 
      type:'post', 
      url:"/quizzes/"+quizId+"/quiz_questions/"+quizQuestionId,
      success: function(msg){ 
        alert("success");
        initializeQuizQuestions();
        setSelectStatus(quizQuestionId, true);
        jQuery("tr[id*='quiz_question_"+quizQuestionId+"']").removeClass('selected');        
      },
      error: function(msg){
        alert("error:" + msg);
      }
    });     
  }
```

Rails will now treat this as if it were a delete request, preserving the REST system.  The reason my PUT example worked was just because in this particular case IE was happy to send a PUT request, but it officially does not support them so it's best to do this for PUT requests as well as DELETE requests.

Comment: Can you please add IE version in your question tag

Comment: this didn't work for me, gives a GET 404, is this because I have  dataType:'script'? When I remove " dataType:'script'", it works great on Chrome but again stops working on IE9, any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at your type attribute `type:'delete'`

[jQuery documentation on type](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/#type):

> The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.

I would instead try and include this with your data and look for it on the server-side, like this:

```
data: {'action': 'delete'},
```

Comment: ah. bollocks.  thanks nick.  I guess a rethink is in order then, which means breaking my lovely restful schema.  :(  grrrr.

Anyone else know any magical ways to get round this?

Comment: Umm did you even verify that IE doesn't support delete as http request method? AFAIK the IE XHR Object supports delete too. but you might need to change `type:'delete'` to `type:'DELETE'`

Comment: @jitter - It doesn't here, only tested in IE8, but the same works in every other browser, trying to find the jQuery dev notes that listed the tested browsers...there was a full list at one point.

Comment: Check modified comment. If I remember correctly IE doesn't uppercase the type in the XHR for all methods as it should

Comment: @Max - Just for kicks, try `type:'DELETE'` and see what happens.  Yep jitter just found the old test notes, IE6 is out IE7 might support it upper cased.

Answer (score 13):

IE 7 and 8 do not support DELETE and PUT methods. I had a problem where IE7,8 would not follow a 302 redirect and IE would use the DELETE or PUT method for the location that it was supposed to redirect to (with a get.)

To ensure that IE7 and 8 work properly, I would use a POST with the parameters:

```
data: {'_method': 'delete'}
```