# Ext JS 3.1.0 RESTful Store DELETE in IE 7 throws exception

Tags: extjs

When using a Restful Store the remove command is throwing an error (Line 1717 of ext-base-debug Error: Invalid argument) when it tries make the DELETE ajax request. Specifically the error is occurring in the asyncRequest method in ext-base when o.conn.send(postData || null); is called. I created a standard Ajax request and used the DELETE method along with the same URL and it worked fine. All other actions in the Store (Create, Read, and Update) work fine.

The EXT JS example RESTful store throws an error as well located here: http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/restful/restful.html

Comment: Does it work in other versions of IE and/or other browsers?  I tried the official sample you linked to in IE 7/8 without an error.  How do you produce it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked down the problem which stemmed from using the ext-basex user extension. If you are using ext-basex try overriding the forceActiveX boolean by adding this to your overrides: Ext.lib.Ajax.forceActiveX = true;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like :

[Problem with jQuery.ajax with 'delete' method in ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456820/problem-with-jquery-ajax-with-delete-method-in-ie)

Comment: No, the request isn't making it to the server at all. The javascript error occurs before actually making the request.

Comment: Which is exactly what is described and explained by this SO question.