# MVC: Using the DELETE verb works in FF but not in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

In my MVC application I have a grid that uses a HTML helper function.
The EditorTemplate looks like;

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <%-- Ajax Delete --%>
        <% if(Model.LeaveId > 0) { %>
        <%: Html.DeleteEmployeeOtherLeave("Delete", Model)%>
        <%} %>
    </td>
    <td><%: Model.LeaveType %></td>
    <td><%: Model.MorningOnlyFlag %></td>
    <td><%: Model.AfternoonOnlyFlag %></td>
    <td><%: Model.DayAmount %></td>
    <td><%: String.Format("{0:ddd MMM d yyyy}", Model.Date)%></td>
</tr>
```

And the HTML helper looks like;

```
        public static MvcHtmlString DeleteEmployeeOtherLeave(this HtmlHelper html, string linkText, Leave _leave)
        {
            return html.RouteLink(linkText, "Default",
                new { _employeeOtherLeaveId = _leave.LeaveId, action = "Delete" },
                new { onclick = "$.ajax({url: this.href, type: 'DELETE', success: function(result) {$('#wholepage').html(result);}}); return false;" }
        }
```

My controller looks like;

```
    [HttpGet]        
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, AdminAccounts, ManagerAccounts")]
    public ActionResult EmployeeAbsence()
    {
        if ((SessionObjects.AbsenceStartDate > DateTime.MinValue) && (SessionObjects.AbsenceEndDate > DateTime.MinValue))
            if (SessionObjects.AbsenceSelectedEmployeeId == 0)
                return View(new AbsenceViewModel()
                {
                    AbsenceStartDate = SessionObjects.AbsenceStartDate,
                    AbsenceEndDate = SessionObjects.AbsenceEndDate
                });
            else
                return View(new AbsenceViewModel(
                    SessionObjects.AbsenceStartDate,
                    SessionObjects.AbsenceEndDate,
                    SessionObjects.AbsenceSelectedEmployeeId
                    ));

        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)]
    public ActionResult Delete(int _employeeOtherLeaveId)
    {
        EmployeeOtherLeaf.Delete(_employeeOtherLeaveId);
        return RedirectToAction("EmployeeAbsence");
    }
    #endregion
```

Using the Delete verb works in FF, but not in IE. Replacing the DELETE verb with POST seems to prevent it from working at all. How do I get this to work in IE?

Comment: FYI: `RedirectToAction` will not work with XHR as you expect it to...

Comment: What exactly happens in IE? Do you get an error? Does a request happen? What kind?

Comment: The error was System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'Delete' was not found on controller 'SHP.Controllers.EmployeeController'.

Comment: When I change DELETE to POST I get System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'EmployeeAbsence' was not found on controller 'SHP.Controllers.EmployeeController'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Don't use HTTP 302 (redirect) with XHR, [because](https://stackoverflow.com/q/199099/75642)...
2. Changing `DELETE` to `POST` won't work, because your action method only executes when you do a `DELETE`:

   ```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)]
   ```

   If you'd change it to accept `POST` then **it would work**.
3. If you're using MVC2+ you can also use HTTP method overriding.

Comment: When I change the DELETE verb to a POST, I find that I call the method and delete the record OK, but the RedirectToAction command does not seem to work. It does in FF but not in IE. I get System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'EmployeeAbsence' was not found on controller 'SHP.Controllers.EmployeeController'.

Comment: @arame3333: Have you tried removing (for test purposes) `Authorize` attribute on the `EmployeeAbsence` action?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out.

http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/01/21/asp.net-mvc-tip-46-ndash-donrsquot-use-delete-links-because.aspx

> **HTML Supports Only GET and POST**
>
> So, the proper thing to do when
>   deleting a database record is to
>   perform an HTTP DELETE operation.
>   Performing an HTTP DELETE does not
>   open a security hole and it does not
>   violate REST principles.
>
> Unfortunately, standard HTML does not
>   support HTTP operations other than GET
>   and POST. A link always performs a GET
>   and a form can perform either a GET or
>   POST. HTML does not support other
>   types of HTTP operations.
>
> According to the HTML 3.1
>   specification, the HTML FORM tag only
>   supports GET and POST. It does not
>   support other HTTP operations such as
>   DELETE or PUT. See
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32.html#form.
>   Furthermore, Internet Explorer only
>   supports GET and POST (see
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534167(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: When I change the DELETE verb to a POST, I find that I call the method and delete the record OK, but the RedirectToAction command does not seem to work. It does in FF but not in IE. I get System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'EmployeeAbsence' was not found on controller 'SHP.Controllers.EmployeeController'.

Answer (score 0):

IE might not support `DELETE` requests. See [Problem with jQuery.ajax with 'delete' method in ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456820/problem-with-jquery-ajax-with-delete-method-in-ie)