# Browser getting error when ajax redirection

Tags: javascript, python, browser

I tried to send an `ajax` `delete` request to this url
But getting a pop up error.

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete": function() {
                //To show the loader                    

                //Ajax call to delete the data          
                $.ajax({
                    type: "DELETE",
                    url: window.location.pathname + id + '/centers/' + c,
                    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                    data: {
                        dc : dc,
                    },
                    success: function(){} }); });
```

Error is

> This web page is being redirected to a new location. Would you like to resend the form data you have typed to the new location?

https://my2.v2.domain.com/grd/net/lb/checker/Env2/centers/11

(This is a demo url to which i am sending.)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide more information - what is triggering the AJAX? What code are you actually using?

Comment: IE 7 and 8 do not support `DELETE` and `PUT` methods..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153917/how-to-send-a-put-delete-request-in-jquery & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456820/problem-with-jquery-ajax-with-delete-method-in-ie

Comment: I tried in firefox 14.0.1 but same error

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for your code, which makes the request. Would help us in looking into the issue.

Comment: What is the 'id' param and why are you adding it to the path name? I think you should separate the path name and id with a '/'.

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers support *redirects* when using the DELETE method (or PUT or POST). The solution is to check in your browser debug console to which location you're being redirected (check the `Location` header), and then adjust the URL in your code to submit directly to that URL so that it does not redirect.

All modern browsers support the DELETE method.