# Why does this MVC action return a 404 response in IE11

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have written an mvc action that works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE11. Using IE11 it returns a 404 response code.

Controller:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult DeleteAction(int ActionID)
{
    return Json(_Logic.DeleteAction(ActionID), JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

Calling JS:

```
Ajax_Proxy.DeleteAction = function (_actionID, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        datatype: 'json',
        url: "/root/someurl/DeleteAction?ActionId=" + _actionID,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) { successCallback(_actionID, data); },
        error: function (data) { failureCallback(data); },
    });
};
```

The Url I am accessing is correct, as it works in other browsers. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Not sure about IE11, but older versions (eg IE8) got a bit confused when a reserved word was used (eg `Ajax.Proxy.void = function` fails).  While it's unlikely 'DeleteAction' is a reserved word (but who knows...), try changing the method name.  Long shot.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already changed the names and it had no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacuse you say that it works in Chrome and Firefox I assume you enabled `PUT/Delete` methods on the IIS?

If yes, I think this may be problem that some IE browsers doesn't support `type: "DELETE"` in Ajax calls. Maybe you are using compability mode to IE8 or something like that?

This problem was already mentioned on SO here: [Problem with jQuery.ajax with 'delete' method in ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456820/problem-with-jquery-ajax-with-delete-method-in-ie) maybe you just discover that IE11 also doesn't support `DELETE`.

Another one good discusion [Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

Comment: Not sure what the issue is but I have changed to a GET and it is working now. Thanks I think you were right about the DELETE not being fully supported

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Ajax_Proxy.DeleteAction = function (_actionID, successCallback, failureCallback) {
return $.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    datatype: 'json',
    url: '@Url.Content("~/root/someurl/DeleteAction/")' + _actionID,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) { successCallback(_actionID, data); },
    error: function (data) { failureCallback(data); },
});
```

};