# PUT and DELETE in REST API

Tags: php, json, api, rest, soap

I have a question that still i have been using PUT and Delete in Web service (REST API) methods for respectively Update a resource and Delete a resource but i am informed now by mobile developers that its not good and always use POST method of HTTP to update and delete. Can i know how far is it true according to current world of technology ?

This is how i used.

```
Create -> Post
Read   -> Get
Update -> Put
Delete -> Delete
```

Suggest me the best API documentation that is available online with best practices.

Comment: [Best online documentation on the different http request methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is mostly related to some browsers or JavaScript frameworks not properly passing `DELETE` and `PUT` on Ajax calls.

There's an overview of the --more or less-- current state for `DELETE` here:

[Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

and here (marked duplicate, but some different answers):

[Which browsers don't support a HTTP DELETE with jQuery.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757187/which-browsers-dont-support-a-http-delete-with-jquery-ajax)

No mention of mobile browsers in particular, though.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of frameworks use a hidden input in a post request to tell the server what rest method it "really" is. Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="PUT"/>
```