# Does ie 6 7 8 support http put& delete request？

Tags: java, rest, internet-explorer

I have read several related posts, and still cannot get the answer.

in this link: [Which browsers don't support a HTTP DELETE with jQuery.ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757187/which-browsers-dont-support-a-http-delete-with-jquery-ajax)， the answer claims that the ie 6 7 8 will support the put& delete http request:

> All recent browsers (and even old ones) support HTTP DELETE.
>
> It's not clear why there is this note in the jQuery documentation,
>   unless they are referring to very old browsers like Netscape 1 or IE
>   2.
>
> For information, I've tried an ajax DELETE request in IE6 and even
>   with this browser it works. If it works with IE6, it's safe to assume
>   it works with any other browser.

but,  in another link: [Problem with jQuery.ajax with 'delete' method in ie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456820/problem-with-jquery-ajax-with-delete-method-in-ie), the answer claims that the ie 6 7 8 will not suppor the put& delete http request, and also provided a walk around:

> IE 7 and 8 do not support DELETE and PUT methods.
>
> To ensure that IE7 and 8 work properly, I would use a POST with the
>   parameters:
>
> `data: {'_method': 'delete'}`

So there is a conflict with below answers, and I donot know the exact answer for this problem.

I want to know the answer of this question, since I want to use a RESTful api at the backend of my website, and this website must support IE 6 7& 8.  If IE6 7 &8 does not support put& delete http requests, can I　continue to use a RESTful api in the backend? can I find a walk-around(I am using Java in the backend)?

Comment: It "must support IE 6 7& 8"... **why?** It's 2016!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch since in China, there are still many old personal computers runing with windows xp, in which the ie 6 is the default broswer.

Comment: My condolences then, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2018, we have strong reasons to not to support old versions of IE, even for users in Chinese small villiges.

From the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP), Windows XP Mainstream support has ended on April 14, 2009. I think for users of XP, since now is 2018, we have strong reasons to recommend them either to update their OS to get a new version of IE, or install new browsers like chrome or firefox.

Note that Microsoft is even changing the name of IE to Edge.

This issue should not be considered anymore.